# How do I make a thread in a service that's guaranteed to run every given specified time?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I need to run some queries every 24 hours, I have a service that's run when the app is launched and the service stays as wanted, How can I have a thread running in that service that inserts some data into the sqlite database?

Comment: If I assume that data is available randomly at runtime from server, how about launching an IntentService from the main service for this task. As soon as, the data comes, it gets queued on to this service.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assure a service stays around like that.  Android can kill a service at any time.  Instead, use JobScheduler to schedule a job to do the inserts in.  Understand that it will not be an exact alarm and will be subject to battery saving rules like doze mode.  Unless your app is whitelisted from those, of course.